# jquery direct id selection doesnt work, tag[id] selection does work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very confused by how the jQuery id-selector works with my html.

Using the `$('#id')` selector, the jQuery Object doesn't contain the DOM Element I want, using the `$('tag[id="id"]')` selector somehow works though.

Can somebody explain why the former doesn't work but the latter does?

```js
console.log($('#1_9:15')[0]);
console.log($('div[id="1_9:15"]')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <td>
        <div id="1_9:15">FREE</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `id`s should not start with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an id that contains a colon `:`, which is how pseudo-classes and `jQuery` extensions are identified. In order for the selector engine to treat it as an id, you must escape it using `\\`.

When using `[id="1_9:15"]` you don't have the same problem because the id is enclosed in brackets and it's easy to identify.

**Example:**

```js
/* Select the div by id escaping the colon. */
console.log($('#1_9\\:15')[0]);

/* Select the div using by id 'the attribute way'. */
console.log($('div[id="1_9:15"]')[0]);

/* Select the div using a pseudo-class. */
console.log($('div:first-child')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <td>
        <div id="1_9:15">FREE</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the pseudo classes :)

Comment: You're welcome @C.S. 

Answer (score 2):

`:` has a special meaning in jQuery selectors. For example, to select all the animated elements, you can do a `$(":animated")`. That's why you need to escape it:

```js
console.log($('#1_9\\:15')[0]);
console.log($('div[id="1_9:15"]')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <td>
        <div id="1_9:15">FREE</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: has a special meaning? Right, can you elaborate?